# h:selectOneMenu selected field is 'null' with @Named and @Produces?

Tags: jsf, cdi

Why this won't work? The drop-down is populated OK, but when submitting the form, the field selectedCatId is null. Why? Please help.

The Bean:

```
@Model
public class MyBean {
 @Named
 @Produces
 private Long selectedCatId;

 @Named
 @Produces
 private List<Category> cats;
}
```

The page:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{selectedCatId}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{cats}" var="cat"
            itemValue="#{cat.id}" itemLabel="#{cat.name}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign to a bean, you can only assign to a bean property.

Just remove `@Named @Produces` from your members, add `@Named` to `MyBean` and replace `#{selectedCatId}` and `#{cats}` by `#{myBean.selectedCatId}` and `#{myBean.cats}`, respectively.

(This assumes that `cats` gets initialized somewhere.)

Comment: Thank you. Right, I didn't know how actually @Produces work, that it can only produce an object, not receive. It's like a getter, not setter.